# Run jQuery script on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bit of script that will run various functions on a window resize,

```
$.event.add(window, 'load', resizeFrame);
$.event.add(window, 'resize', resizeFrame);

function resizeFrame(){
    // various scripts //
}
```

This works absolutely fine, and the scripts I run in there work also. I then have a separate script that sets the height of various divs on document load, which also works just fine.

```
var h = 0,
    target = $('.home #content .items-row .item article');

target.each(function(){
    if (h < $(this).height()){
        h = $(this).height();
    }
}); 
target.each(function () {
    $(this).css("height", h + 'px');
});
$('.testimonials .items-row').each(function () {
    $('.span4 article', this).css('height',
        Math.max.apply( Math, 
            $.map($('.span4 article', this), function(x) {
                return $(x).height();
            })
        )
    );
});
```

However when i try to combine the two, my divs will resize once on load, but not again on window resize. This is how i have combined the two,

```
function articleResize(){
    var h = 0,
        target = $('.home #content .items-row .item article');

    target.each(function(){
        if (h < $(this).height()){
            h = $(this).height();
        }
    }); 
    target.each(function () {
        $(this).css("height", h + 'px');
    });

    $('.testimonials .items-row').each(function () {
        $('.span4 article', this).css('height',
            Math.max.apply( Math, 
                $.map($('.span4 article', this), function(x) {
                    return $(x).height();
                })
            )
        );
    });
}

$.event.add(window, 'load', resizeFrame);
$.event.add(window, 'resize', resizeFrame);

function resizeFrame(){
    articleResize();
}
```

If anyone has any clues it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

as background here is the `resizeFrame` in its entirety,

```
function resizeFrame(){

    var screenWidth = $(window).width();

    function phoneEnable(){
        $('#MainNav ul.nav').prependTo('.sidr-inner').addClass('nav-list nav-collapse');
        $('#MainSocial ul.roundIcons').prependTo('.sidr-inner');
    };
    function phoneDisable(){
        $('#sidr ul.nav').prependTo('#MainNav').removeClass('nav-list nav-collapse');
        $('#sidr ul.roundIcons').prependTo('#MainSocial');
    }

    if (screenWidth >= 980){
        phoneDisable();
    } else{
        phoneEnable();
    };

        var highestBox = 0;
    $('.blog-featured .item article', this).each(function(){
        if($(this).height() > highestBox)
        highestBox = $(this).height();
        });
    $('.blog-featured .item article',this).height(highestBox);

    articleResize();
};
```

Comment: i don't get the logic behind resize formula, it looks like it just sets the height to tallest element of all other elements.

Comment: Can we see the "various scripts" in `resizeFrame` ?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer thats exactly what it does, which bit is illogical?
I have added the 'various scripts'.

Comment: A sample of your HTML (i.e. in a JSFiddle) would make this easier to test/fix :)

Comment: Side-note: You don't need to append `+ 'px'` for jQuery CSS properties like height. It will assume numbers are `px` values anyway.

Comment: I have replicated the issue in a JSFiddle, however the resizing of the window would normally affect div width as im using Bootstrap, so I cant replicate the actual action and effect upon a window resize....if you get me!

Comment: Added a JSFiddle in answer below. Had to comment out the unrelated code to get it to run.

Comment: I did a bit more testing and it appears that `$.event.add(window, 'load', resizeFrame);` is sensitive to where it is placed. If registered too late it will not fire. You should stick with the standard jQuery `resize` and `load` event handling as outlined below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load event was not firing in the samples I tried.

Instead of your current event registration try this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9SR5/1/

```
// jQuery DOM ready shortcut event handler (with locally scoped $)
jQuery(function($){

   // Register for window resize
   $(window).resize(resizeFrame);

   // Do initial resize
   resizeFrame();
});
```

### Update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j9SR5/5/

You are setting a fixed height, so the next time you resize the height is as specified previous (and will not change). The new JSFiddle resets the heights to their natural state first.

```
// Revert to height based on content
target.each(function () {
    $(this).css("height", '');
});
```

Comment: This is a much better approach! I have re written my code this way so thank you for your help, unfortunately though, despite this being helpful i am still faced with the issue that when the window resizes, the divs that get their height set from the tallest of the elements will not change. They get their height initially from this script, but then wont resize again upon each window resize.

Comment: @Tim Wilkinson: Sorted. It was obvious once you spelt that out. The height were obviously what they were previously set to. Need to reset them to inherited values first.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just wrapping the standard resize DOM event, eg.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

jQuery may do some work to ensure that the resize event gets fired consistently in all browsers, but I'm not sure if any of the browsers differ,

Comment: prior to the second half of the script i added the resize function works just fine and is cross browser tested, its just the addition of this script wont run on resize.